# Can't connect to Square Register from web app

Tags: square-connect

I have used this exact example from the [square api reference](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/web-api-android):

```
<a href="intent:#Intent;action=com.squareup.register.action.CHARGE;package=com.squareup;S.browser_fallback_url=https://my.website.com/index.html;S.com.squareup.register.WEB_CALLBACK_URI=https://my.website.com/index.html;S.com.squareup.register.CLIENT_ID=sq0ids-yOurCLieNtId;S.com.squareup.register.API_VERSION=v1.3;i.com.squareup.register.TOTAL_AMOUNT=100;S.com.squareup.register.CURRENCY_CODE=USD;S.com.squareup.register.TENDER_TYPES=com.squareup.register.TENDER_CARD,com.squareup.register.TENDER_CARD_ON_FILE,com.squareup.register.TENDER_CASH,com.squareup.register.TENDER_OTHER;end">Send me $</a>
```

However, trying to click the link causes this error in the Register App:
**Unexpected Developer Error**

> Register API must be started with startActivityForResult() in the same
>   task. It looks like the caller either used startActivity() or used
>   startActivityForResult() from a finished activity or with the
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.

Comment: which version of the Square Point of Sale app do you have, and which of Android?

Comment: Square POS is 4.62.1
Phone is a Pixel XL running Android 7.1.2

Comment: I'm now getting this error too for a web app that used to work.  Square was updated recently, I can't figure out if there's a bug in the way I'm calling it or a bug in their code.

Comment: The latest version of Square Point of Sale had a bug that affected some users of the web api. A fix has been pushed to the Google play store. Try updating your app version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message here is incorrect. The example from the documentation uses "https://my.website.com/index.html". You should replace this with a valid callback URI from your site and make sure to register it on the Square developer portal under the "Register API" tab.

You will also need to replace the example com.squareup.register.CLIENT_ID Intent extra with your Square assigned application ID from the developer portal.

Comment: Update: This error was due to a bug in the API. It has since been fixed. If you update the parameters mentioned above you should be able to take transactions now.